# Javascript load more images of the array onclick. Using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onclick, load

I'm trying to make my website a little bit faster, and for that, I'm trying to make a button that on each click presents more images. For example: a user can see 5 images, and if the user wants to see 5 more he can, by clicking on the button.

So for now only got this, and i really think it's not the right way.

HTML ->

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let pic of photoList">
    <h1>{{pic?.username}}</h1>
    <h2>{{pic?.name}}</h2>
    <img src={{pic?.picture}}>
</ion-card>
    <button ion-button (click)="load()">Load More Images</button>
```

Js ->

```
load() {
    firebase.database().ref('HomeList').limitToLast(5).on('value', snapshot => {
      this.photoList = [];
      snapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.photoList.push({
          id: snap.key,
          name: snap.val().name,
          username: snap.val().username,
          picture: snap.val().picture,
          email: snap.val().email,
          uid: snap.val().uid,
          rating: snap.val().rating
        });
        console.log(this.photoList);
        return false
      });
      return this.photoList.reverse();
    });
  }
```

Comment: what does it mean 5 more? 5 newly created images(like a refresh button)? or you trying to add pagination?

Comment: I'm saying is that, for example are a total of 18 images on the page (and more can be added), you can automatically see 5, but the rest is hidden, and only loaded when the user clicks on the button.

Answer (score 0):

so you need a pagination try to use  .startAfter(number) and .limit(number); assuming this.current = 0; sets in constructor();

```
load() {
firebase.database().ref('HomeList').startAfter(this.current).limit(5).on('value', snapshot => {
  this.photoList = [];
  snapshot.forEach(snap => {
    this.photoList.push({
      id: snap.key,
      name: snap.val().name,
      username: snap.val().username,
      picture: snap.val().picture,
      email: snap.val().email,
      uid: snap.val().uid,
      rating: snap.val().rating
    });
    console.log(this.photoList);
    this.current = this.current  + photoList.length;
    return false
  });
  return this.photoList.reverse();
});
```

}

Comment: That's for firestore, im using real time db